# Countif alternative

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Im trying to create a file that contains the count of each employee's day off for the whole year. Right now, i'm thinking of using countif:

```
=COUNTIF(C21:AG21,"L")+COUNTIF(C35:AG35,"L").... up to last month
```

For me, It's a little bit long and messy. Is there any way to shorten it or any alternative? Thanks!

[image: countif alternative]

Comment: Not really.. excel likes to have data and reports separately. By combining them you are guaranteeing yourself some fiddly formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMPRODUCT` works in my test.

*emp2* can be changed for a cell reference and `$A$21:$A$35` to cover all employee names across the year, while `$C$21:$CG$35` covers all the days in the year.

`=SUMPRODUCT(($A$21:$A$35="emp2")*($C$21:$CG$35="L"))`

Comment: It works! But still need to understand more about `SUMPRODUCT` tho. 

I'm going to search about it. Thanks!

Comment: Chandoo has a pretty good explanation:  http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/11/10/excel-sumproduct-formula/